# Get FSharp.Core.dll to 'Copy Local' for an F# library project that targets .NET 6

Tags: f#, msbuild

I am building an F# library targeting .NET 6 that will be 'hosted' by another executable (it's actually an Excel add-in). It's a library, so the `OutputType` of the F# project is the implicit default `<OutputType>Library</OutputType>`. In this case the F# build does not copy FSharp.Core.dll to the output directory. When running my host, it loads my output library but then fails since the F# dependency `FSharp.Core.dll` is not present.

My project file is just the default library template:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Library.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

If I change to `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>` then the `FSharp.Core.dll` **is** copied to the output directory.

If I change to `<TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>` then the `FSharp.Core.dll` **is** copied to the output directory, even for a library.

I have read the [Notes and Guidance about on FSharp.Core](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-compiler-docs/fsharp-core-notes.html) about this and in my case the project is more like an application and really should have the `FSharp.Core.dll` locally, although the project output is a .dll.

There is a property called `<FSharpCoreIncludeDocFileInOutput>true</FSharpCoreIncludeDocFileInOutput>` that controls whether the `FSharp.Core.xml` documentation is included in the output, but I couldn't find anything for the `FSharp.Core.dll` itself.

I was hoping to find some project file property that will allow me to set the `FSharp.Core.dll` as 'Copy Local' but couldn't fine anything, nor can I see where the F# build files are using the `OutputType` property.

Comment: Try `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>`. This property is `false` in libraries, but `true` in executables. Enabling it fixes issue for me locally (sdk 6.0.101)

Comment: Yes! Wonderful - it works - thank you. Please make that an 'answer'?

Comment: I've done additional research and found that `CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies` is affected by [`EnableDynamicLoading`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#enabledynamicloading) which should be used in such cases

Comment: I see - yes `EnableDynamicLoading` is an even better fit for my use case.